# Is it possible to index a running total to speed up window functions?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to execute:

```sql
    SELECT cust_id, SUM(cost)
    FROM purchases
    WHERE purchase_time BETWEEN('2018-01-01', '2019-01-01')
    GROUP BY cust_id
```

But with a large number of rows, I expect each record will have to be loaded to aggregate the appropriate SUM. What I want to do is have an index like:

```sql
    CREATE INDEX purchase_sum 
    ON purchases(cust_id, purchase_time, 
    SUM(cost) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id 
    ORDER BY purchase_time) AS rolling_cost)
```

From which I'd like an index that looks like:

```
 cust_id    time    rolling_cost
--------   ------  --------------
   1        Jan 1       5
   1        Jan 2       12
   1        Jan 3       14
   1        Jan 4       20
   1        Jan 5       24
   2        Jan 1       1
   2        Jan 2       7
   2        Jan 3       11
   2        Jan 4       14
   2        Jan 5       19
   3        Jan 1       4
   3        Jan 2       5
   3        Jan 3       10
   3        Jan 4       21
   3        Jan 5       45
```

From this, my original query could be computed by simply subtracting 2 known values per cust_id, loosely as `cost_in_window = rolling_cost('2019-01-01') - rolling_cost('2018-01-01')`, which would not require loading anything from the source table.

Is this doable as an index? Or is there another way of accomplishing the same goal?

Comment: `an index that looks like` ... an index is a data structure, e.g. a B-tree.  It is not a table.

Comment: ... consider stepping over to a RDMS which supports native [Materialized view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view), that is what you seams to be asking here.. SQL Server supports it `WITH SCHEMABINDING` with indexes meaning the Materialized view is auto updated when data changes, more or less the same why how triggers could do it..

Answer (score 3):

You might find that this is faster:

```
select c.cust_id,
       (select sum(p.cost)
        from purchases p
        where p.cust_id = c.cust_id and
              p.purchase_time >= '2018-01-01' and
              p.purchase_time < '2019-01-01' and
       ) as total_cost
from customers c
having total_cost is not null;
```

Then, this can use an index on `purchases(cust_id, purchase_time, cost)`.  *Only* the index is needed for calculating the amount.  That is a savings.  More importantly, there is no overall aggregations -- and that can be a bigger savings that makes up for doing the calculation on all customers.

However, with the same index, this might be a bit better:

```
select c.cust_id,
       (select sum(p.cost)
        from purchases p
        where p.cust_id = c.cust_id and
              p.purchase_time >= '2018-01-01' and
              p.purchase_time < '2019-01-01'
       ) as total_cost
from customers c
where exists (select 1
              from purchases p
              where p.cust_id = c.cust_id and
                    p.purchase_time >= '2018-01-01' and
                    p.purchase_time < '2019-01-01' 
             );
```

EDIT:

The only way to implement what you want is by explicitly including a cumulative sum column in the data.  That would require rephrasing the query (to do the subtraction that you want) and to have triggers to maintain the value.

If the historical data never changes, this might be a reasonable approach.  However, updates or inserts of earlier rows could become quite expensive.

Comment: This is certainly better than the unindexed approach, but still doesn't achieve what I'm trying for. The same idea without the GROUP BY: imagine 1B purchase records, and you want the sum for this year, which has maybe 100M such records. Even with your suggested index, 100M additions will occur. Not great. But if I maintain a rolling total (i.e., foreach record, store the sum of all records from the start until that record's time), I can calculate this in 2*logn time.  Given the lack of anyone saying it's possible, I think I can infer it's not :)

Comment: *" imagine 1B purchase records, and you want the sum for this year, which has maybe 100M such records"* @Rollie that would be a great time to hire a DBA then..  Also Big O notion for the SQL language is pretty meaningless as SQL is declarative in nature where you define what you want to have not how to get it.. Also internally the optimizer could optimize and rewrite this SQL into a other SQL If you would a good performance indication use `EXPLAIN [FORMAT=JSON] <query>` dont calculate it yourself or think what might happen under the hood ..

Answer (score 1):

Here is an index which might help your query:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON purchases (purchase_time, cust_id, cost);
```

This should at the very least let MySQL throw away all records which don't meet the purchase time range.  Then, this index also covers the `cust_id` and `cost` columns, meaning that MySQL would only need to perform an index scan to compute the cost sums for each group of customer records.

Comment: This is an improvement, but not what I'm trying to do in this question. In the contrived example, it works fine, but given a much larger data set (maybe 1m unique custs with 100 purchases per day) the difference will be more pronounced.

Comment: I answered the first part of your question, which was tuning that query.  If you need help with the workaround, I don't understand, so you might want to better explain.  Yes -- keeping track of a rolling sum with a trigger is in fact one way to avoid even running your first query.

Comment: My question was "Is it possible to index a running total to speed up window functions?", as can be seen in the title; not "can an index make this query faster?" The trigger approach is a more applicable answer, but as far as I know would require the querying app know about the generated field, rather than letting the query optimizer use it automatically on aggregate queries.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  Please explain better the logic behind the workaround you have in mind using window functions (I can't imagine one).You d

Comment: @Rollie I consider your response above to be rude. Your question was twofold: 'is this doable as an index?' (from which we can infer that the answer is 'no') and 'Or is there another way of accomplishing the same goal?' which TB has generously attempted to answer.